# Dynamic type depends on first attribute

Tags: typescript

I have an object:

```
const Actions = {
  entityOne: {
    doSomething: () => ...,
    doSomething2: () => ...
  },
  entityTwo: {
    doSomething3: () => ...,
    doSomething4: () => ...
  }
}
```

I want to have a action getter like:

```
const getAction = (
  entity: keyof typeof Actions, // this returns "entityOne" | "entityTwo"
  action: ? // but this?
) => Actions[entity][action]
```

Can I get action type depends on entity? that I pass to getAction function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [generic type parameters to constrain the function parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#using-type-parameters-in-generic-constraints), you can index the `Actions` object to get desired the return type:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=22&ssc=10&pln=22&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAgsKBLcEYF4YG8BQMYCmYyUAngPJgEBc2e+MAJiAMogC2BUAFkmAOa0AFAEoMAPhgByAIxSANPXzM2nHn34AmYWPSTNi-AF9DhYkjIAVAO4hauBk1YcuvAQGYdE6e4VKnqq4aACxeejDBpiY4RgDcODigkLD8XAjI4BgwADz0ANIADIQAHlBEjGgA1gSkIABmMGQADgT18IgokKZ5MiVlYBUw1bUNza0N6Z0QANqFALqK4kJEJKS0hfIwAIYd4OsyIrRjbZOoswVzszJz3qeQ0ysWpJc7GWBz8YmosABOBBAAVwANlBephUlA7kIpI8yJQCAppCoXOoBFIRPEAPSYxwAPQA-F9kjA-oCQZoshCoTDzFZbIipMi1G5+MF0VicQwCQlsYQoMAAHRCnBAA)

```ts
const Actions = {
  entityOne: {
    doSomething: () => '1',
    doSomething2: () => 2,
  },
  entityTwo: {
    doSomething3: () => '3',
    doSomething4: () => 4,
  },
};

const getAction = <
  K0 extends keyof typeof Actions,
  K1 extends keyof typeof Actions[K0],
>(entity: K0, action: K1): typeof Actions[K0][K1] => Actions[entity][action];

const result1 = getAction('entityOne', 'doSomething'); // () => string
const result2 = getAction('entityTwo', 'doSomething4'); // () => number
// etc...
```